# Python Script for logging into website does not input login info

Tags: python, html, excel, syntax

I am trying to make a script that will login into a website and then scrape the data from a specific page that is on the website that can only be accessed after logging in. The data does not come through on the IDLE shell regardless if I am already logged in or not, so this tells me that the website must have some sort of verification key or ID that I am not seeing within the login website code. I have reviewed the code several times for the login site, but I cannot find anything else that I might be missing. I am not sure if I am allowed to post HTML data for other websites here, but here is the script I am writing.

Please excuse the commented section labeled excel scripts:

I have already tried using lxml and beautifulsoup for navigation purposes, but it does not seem to have any effect. I have tried a similar script on other, simpler websites and it seemed to work there for the most part.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

USERNAME = <username>
PASSWORD = <password>

LOGIN_URL = "https://www.tm3.com/homepage/login.jsf"
URL = "https://www.tm3.com/mmdrewrite/mmd/14902.faces"

def main():
session_requests = requests.session()

# Get login csrf token
result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath('//input[@name= 
"javax.faces.ViewState"]/@value')))[0]
# Create payload
payload = {
    "username": USERNAME, 
    "password": PASSWORD, 
    "javax.faces.ViewState": authenticity_token
}

# Perform login
result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = 
dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

# Scrape url
result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL))
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
print('',result.content)

"""
#excel scripts
def excel():
import xlwt
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding= "utf-8")
sheet1= book.add_sheet("Sheet1")


#for loop for putting data into different cells
num=0
row = sheet1.row(num)

row.write(num,test)
print("EVEN:" , test)
print("ODD:" , ODD)
book.save("Testing.xls")

"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

I want the webpage to be printed in its entirety, but instead the script just prints out the login webpage

Comment: Have you printed `authenticity_token` to see if it looks correct?  Are you sure it is supposed to be passed in the data, and not in the header?

Comment: Why are you calling `list(set(...))` to fetch the authenticity token?  The usual reason for that is to avoid duplicate values, but it seems odd that there could be multiple authenticity tokens on the page.

Comment: If there _are_ multiple authenticity tokens on the page, you probably want to take care to fetch the correct one, instead of fetching one at random.

Comment: I printed the authenticity token and it seems correct. it is the only set of text that can look like a authenticity token of some kind

for context, it prints this value:(rO0ABXVyABNbTGphdmEubGFuZy5PYmplY3Q7kM5YnxBzKWwCAAB4cAAAAAN0AAdfaWQ4ODgwcHQACi9sb2dpbi5qc3A=)

I called list set in order to see if there are multiple authenticity tokens actually. 

using

   `list(set)..` and     `tree.xpath` does not seem to change the result

Comment: Are the parentheses supposed to be part of the value?

Comment: they are not a part of the value. the parentheses are there because without them I was being given syntax errors